# How do you read a certain size of memory from an arbitrary address and write it's content to a file?

Tags: linux, memory

OS : linux.

I am looking for tools or tips to write code (if and only if necessary) to write the contents of an address to a file for further investigation.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: have a look at http://linux.die.net/man/2/ptrace. With this you can attach a process to yours and read memory from that process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Core dump is a full snapshot of the process memory.

If you have `gcore` available it will generate you a core dump of a running process without terminating it. Else you may use `kill -ABRT` to kill the process and generate core dump.

Make sure `ulimit -c` is set to `unlimited` (or set it with `ulimit -c unlimited`).

If you *really* want only a small segment dumped have a look at [this](http://www.delorie.com/gnu/docs/gdb/gdb_56.html) section of GDB manual.

Comment: dump memory is what I was looking for. I still have to figure out why do I have "cannot access memory" errors.